# Merging My Setting and My Account in WordPress Menu Structure BuddyPanel

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I've been stuck trying to figure out how to merge My Menu Structure in WordPress. I want to merge My Accounts Gravity Form into My Settings page in WordPress Menu that is running Buddypanel. I've tried creating a sub menu inside My Setting and can't seem to connect the dots.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide code and elaborate your problem more clearly instead of saying "Can't seem to connect the dots". E.g., what is the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: Thank you for the response Mark.I am having a hard time figuring out how to extend the submenu of the user profile page for buddyPress.  I want to add things like: Update Credit Card, Invoices, etc....